# Calculate amount of agent using a path

Tags: counter, anylogic

I already had this question before but than for transporters. In my model I want to calculate the amounts of agents using a path by using a counter as variable, but hower the method I'm currently using for transporters does not work for agents without transporters.

I currently create a node (see first image) which the agents should pass and put a counter in here (see picture 2). But however this seems not to work for just using agents without transporter. Is there another method? Thanks.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Do you use those rectangular nodes for something else also, or just for counting purpose?

Comment: @YasharAhmadov they re just for counting purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can do, as a dumb solution is to have 2 events in your agent... one that is cyclic every 100 miliseconds or so that does absolutely nothing

and another one that is a conditional event that has the condition:

```
node.contains(getX(),getY())
```

on this event you will make the count.

when the movement begins (however you do that), you restart the conditional event:

```
event.restart();
```

Comment: My current solution is checking for all the agents by indeed an event to see which coordinates they are in, when the coordinates are in the path, a counter added this agent in the counter! So it is indeed with the logic of this.

Answer (score 1):

I think using rectangular nodes for counting is overkill. Here is how I do it:

Create a variable in the main, let's call it `counterNodes`. It should be of type `int[][]`. Inside the initial value type `new int[5][5]` (assuming you have 5 nodes and 5x5 possible combinations (pairs)).

If you don't have `origin` and `destination` variables for your Person agent, create ones. Or skip this step if you already have something with this logic.

And I am assuming your nodes are called node0, node1, node2, etc.

If you are using `moveTo` blocks, on enter, get the agents' origins and destinations number and increment the counter.

```
Integer a=(int) Integer.parseInt(agent.origin.getName().substring(4));
Integer b=(int) Integer.parseInt(agent.destination.getName().substring(4));

counterNodes[a][b]+=1;
```

Comment: Thanks, if nodes are not the solution, I can indeed code it, I don't think this is the solution for my specific case but I will figure something out!